# How to write Unit Test case for Switch Statement that returns Component in Jest with React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

When I writing test case, I was able to reach out to case 0, but not able to reach other 1

```js
const tabContent = (isCurrent) => {
    switch (isCurrent) {
      case 0:
        return <Component 1 />;
      case 1:
        return <Component 2 />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Where does isCurrent come from? What causes its value to change? Why did you write this functionality to begin with - what interaction does it actually handle? Without some context and a [mre] it's impossible to say how it should be tested.

Comment: isCurrent is a variable defined inside useState hook. onClick of button am changing the value of useState.

Answer (score -1):

Then set isCurrent to 1 to go to the first case tabContent(1)
Any other value wil go to the default

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).